# DbSet<T>.Add(T entity) throws System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a EF6 Code First model with an entity that looks like this:

```
[Table("Updates")]
public class Update
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="varchar(max)")]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedTimestampUtc { get; set; }
}
```

My db context class looks like this:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    public GlobalizationContext() : base(ConnectionString)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Update> UpdatesDbSet { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Update> Updates //IUnitOfWork implementation
    {
        get { return UpdatesDbSet; }
    }

    public async Task AddUpdateTokenAsync(Update updateToken)
    {
        var entity = UpdatesDbSet.Add(updateToken);
        var result = await SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

When I hit the `var entity = UpdatesDbSet.Add(updateToken);` line, I generate the following exception:

```
SetUpdateTokenAsync(Update) System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Configure>b__3(Tuple`2 pm)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each[T](IEnumerable`1 ts, Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1 propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
```

Looking at the `DbSet` object and the `Update` object, both appear to be instantiated, and I don't understand why `.Add()` would need to find matching elements.  Can someone explain to me what the problem is here, and what I should do to correct it?

**UPDATE**

Per request, the following are the EF configurations in my web.config file:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>
. . .
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

... I realized this was wrong, and changed it to:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

This did not change the symptoms.  I also tried the suggested decorator change as follows:

```
[Column("Comments", TypeName="varchar")]
public string Comments { get; set; }
```

...again, with no difference in behavior.

**UPDATE 2**

So I think I should have mentioned this earlier, I don't know if it's significant (but based upon the direction the suggestions are going, it looks like it might be), but I am pointing to a pre-existing database.  The table in question is created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Updates](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedTimestampUtc] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Comments] [varchar](MAX) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](260) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Updates] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Updates] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Updates_Id]  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Updates] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Updates_CreatedTimestampUtc]  DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [CreatedTimestampUtc]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Updates] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Updates_CreatedBy]  DEFAULT (suser_sname()) FOR [CreatedBy]
GO
```

Comment: Show your `Web/App.config`. It's seems like `varchar(max)` in your `[Column(TypeName="varchar(max)")]` attribute doesn't match any configured store type. The reason why you're getting this on `Add()` is simply because it's the first time you're accessing the `DbSet` then invoking its internal `Initialize()` method.

Comment: I can't show the whole thing as it contains business sensitive data.  Is there something specific you want to see?  This is going against a SQL Server instance, so I'd assume `varchar(max)` would be appropriate for that.

Comment: Try to change the `[Column(TypeName="varchar(max)")]` for `[Column("Comments", TypeName="varchar")]`

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs, The section related to EntityFramework

Comment: @haim770 I added the info you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a combination of a couple of things.

- My migrations were in a strange state; since my main (startup)
  project was not the same as my data access project, and there were
  different connection strings in them, EF absolutely refused to
  properly generate the migration code even when explicitly told in the Package manager console which project to work off of, with the same ridiculous
  error... I stumbled across this by accident, and I was rather annoyed
  at the cryptic nature of the message compared to the problem.
- I was overthinking the `MAX` values; it turns out EF6 defaults to
  `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for all string columns unless explicitly stated
  otherwise (which I personally think is a really bad idea) -- or
  through convention, I guess.  By just specifying `VARCHAR` and then
  tweaking the migration code, I could get `VARCHAR(MAX)`... for all
  string properties where `NVARCHAR(MAX)` was not appropriate, I had to
  put in `StringLength` decorators.

So finally, I now have new cryptic errors... but that's for another question.  Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change

```
[Column(TypeName="varchar(max)")]
public string Comments { get; set; }
```

to

```
[Column(TypeName="[varchar](MAX) NULL")]
public string Comments { get; set; }
```

Comment: This does not seem to fix the issue.

Comment: Could you remove that column at all and see if that column a problem.

Comment: Also try to change Id column to have Guid type and UpdateId as a name or change it to int type. There can be an issue with  uniqueidentifier with Guid type